# two dictionaries/list comprehension on condition

Tags: python, json, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have two lists of dictionaries:

1.

```
"baby_bottlefeed" : [
    {
      "pk" : 1,
      "amountML" : 22.600000381469727,
      "isFormula" : 1,
      "babyid" : 1,
      "date" : 1688970600
    },
    {
      "pk" : 2,
      "amountML" : 50,
      "isFormula" : 1,
      "babyid" : 1,
      "date" : 1689132692.5657411
    },
    {
      "pk" : 3,
      "amountML" : 50,
      "isFormula" : 1,
      "babyid" : 1,
      "date" : 1689171473.9392519
    },
```

2. 

```
"tracker_detail" : [
    {
      "trackerDetailId" : 1,
      "trackerDescription" : "some note1",
      "trackerType" : 6,
      "babyId" : 1
    },
    {
      "trackerDetailId" : 3,
      "trackerDescription" : "some note2",
      "trackerType" : 11,
      "babyId" : 1
    },
```

I want to create a new dictionary/update the first one with  the second one with "trackerDescription" as a "note" based on 2 condition: 1. PK from the 1st  one is the same as trackerDetailId from the second one and trackerType from 2nd one is 6. The ones that  does not the condition should get  a note saying "no note"

Desired output:

```
"baby_bottlefeed" : [
    {
      "pk" : 1,
      "amountML" : 22.600000381469727,
      "isFormula" : 1,
      "babyid" : 1,
      "date" : 1688970600,
      "note" : "some note1"
    },
    {
      "pk" : 2,
      "amountML" : 50,
      "isFormula" : 1,
      "babyid" : 1,
      "date" : 1689132692.5657411,
      "note" : "no note"
    },
    {
      "pk" : 3,
      "amountML" : 50,
      "isFormula" : 1,
      "babyid" : 1,
      "date" : 1689171473.9392519
      "note" : "no note"
    }
```

my code produces "no note" in every case.

```
     for dict in data_dict['baby_bottlefeed']:

        for dict_trackerdetail in data_dict['tracker_detail']:
            dict['note'] = dict_trackerdetail['trackerDescription'] if (
                dict_trackerdetail['trackerType'] == 6 and dict_trackerdetail['trackerDetailId'] == dict['pk']) else 'no note'
```

i will appreciate any help and tips1
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create temporary dictionary from `dct2` to ease the search:

```py
dct1 = {
    "baby_bottlefeed": [
        {
            "pk": 1,
            "amountML": 22.600000381469727,
            "isFormula": 1,
            "babyid": 1,
            "date": 1688970600,
        },
        {
            "pk": 2,
            "amountML": 50,
            "isFormula": 1,
            "babyid": 1,
            "date": 1689132692.5657411,
        },
        {
            "pk": 3,
            "amountML": 50,
            "isFormula": 1,
            "babyid": 1,
            "date": 1689171473.9392519,
        },
    ]
}

dct2 = {
    "tracker_detail": [
        {
            "trackerDetailId": 1,
            "trackerDescription": "some note1",
            "trackerType": 6,
            "babyId": 1,
        },
        {
            "trackerDetailId": 3,
            "trackerDescription": "some note2",
            "trackerType": 11,
            "babyId": 1,
        },
    ]
}

tmp = {
    td["trackerDetailId"]: td for td in dct2["tracker_detail"] if td["trackerType"] == 6
}

for bb in dct1["baby_bottlefeed"]:
    if bb["pk"] in tmp:
        bb["note"] = tmp[bb["pk"]].get("trackerDescription")
    else:
        bb["note"] = "no note"

print(dct1)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "baby_bottlefeed": [
        {
            "pk": 1,
            "amountML": 22.600000381469727,
            "isFormula": 1,
            "babyid": 1,
            "date": 1688970600,
            "note": "some note1",
        },
        {
            "pk": 2,
            "amountML": 50,
            "isFormula": 1,
            "babyid": 1,
            "date": 1689132692.565741,
            "note": "no note",
        },
        {
            "pk": 3,
            "amountML": 50,
            "isFormula": 1,
            "babyid": 1,
            "date": 1689171473.939252,
            "note": "no note",
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're updating the first dictionary for *every* second dictionary in the `tracker_detail` list. I would change your code like so:

```py
for dict_bottlefeed in data_dict['baby_bottlefeed']:
    for dict_trackerdetail in data_dict['tracker_detail']:
        if dict_trackerdetail['trackerType'] == 6 and dict_trackerdetail['trackerDetailId'] == dict_bottlefeed['pk']:
            dict_bottlefeed['note'] = dict_trackerdetail['trackerDescription']
            break
    else:
        dict_bottlefeed['note'] = 'no note'
```

Also, don't shadow built-ins. Doing that won't allow you to instantiate a `dict` class anymore.